# How to call a single, general jquery function to post any of many different forms on a page?

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

Learning jquery, so please be kind :)

Using PHP, I have a table with many (let's say 50) rows - each with a product ID and a product Description, and then a variety of other fields that differ line to line depending on the type of product.

My approach is to have one form for each of the 50 products (each uniquely named using the product ID) and be able to submit the particular form and fields in that form using a button without having to write a different jquery function for each product/form.

Have been googling for god knows how long, and I must be asking wrong, as I can't find anything that accomplishes what this pseudo code would do:

```
<form name='frm_for_product_123'>
   <input type="hidden" name="product_id" id="product_id" value="123">
   <input type="text" name="description" id="description" value="blah blah blah for 123">
   <input type="text" name="color" id="color" value="blue">
   <input type="text" name="size" id="size" value="medium">
   <input type="button" value="Apply">
</form>

<form name='frm_for_product_456'>
   <input type="hidden" name="product_id" id="product_id" value="456">
   <input type="text" name="description" id="description" value="blah blah blah for 456">
   <input type="text" name="weight" id="weight" value="heavy">
   <input type="button" value="Apply">
</form>

etc., etc. etc. for all 50 products
```

I want the user to be able to click on the Apply button for that row, and have the values OF that row go to a single, general function that will post that form and do the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming from your question you want to submit via Ajax. Not entirely clear if that's the case, but here's an example of how to do it with jQuery:

```
$('form').submit(
    function (e) {
        // stop form submission
        e.preventDefault();
        // do any custom logic here
            // then submit - $(this) = current form, 
            // .serialize() turns the form into post data
        $.post('form processing url', $(this).serialize(), myCallbackUpdateFunction);
    }
);
```

Comment: This looks quite promising. On the first line where 'form' is that general? In other words, will this be called by ANY form on the page?

Comment: Correct. You could filter it down if needed by applying a selector in front of form or adding a class to all the forms you want it to apply to-- in case you have a search form on every page, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery AJAX functions to do this:

```
//bind a click event handler to the buttons for each form
$('form').children('[type="button"]').on('click', function () {

    //get this button's form element
    var $form = $(this).parent();

    //create AJAX call using form's attributes
    $.ajax({
        url  : $form.attr('action'),
        type : $form.attr('method'),
        data : $form.serialize(),
        success : function (data) {
            //you can now access the server response in the `data` variable
        }
    });

    //stop default behavior of button click and event propagation
    return false;
});
```

You don't have to use forms, you can save data in `data-attributes` on elements:

Then you just pass the ID along with the AJAX request:

```
    $.ajax({
        url  : '<url>',
        type : '<get || post>',
        data : { 'product_id' : $(this).attr('data-id') },
        success : function (data) {
            //you can now access the server response in the `data` variable
        }
    });
```

Comment: On the first line:
Must it be 'type="button"'?  I'm thinking down the road for another button, like Delete or something, so could you use:
    $('form').children('[class="save_button"]').on('click', function () {....}
and
    $('form').children('[class="delete_button"]').on('click', function () {....}

I chose forms since each product has different data elements, it seemed to make more sense to pass the form (with whatever fields it might have), leaving the more compicated logic to parse it in the hands of the server.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best answer or not, but it demonstrates exactly what I'm trying to accomplish:
[jquery post - update db - multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302234/jquery-post-update-db-multiple-rows)

Will be working from this unless I hear a better solution - Thanks Gaurav Porwal!